# How get Word editor for appointment in viewpage

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, vsto

How i can run the following code with view page

```
var inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
var document = (Word.Document)inspector.WordEditor;
```

it working fine with Edit view but the main[view] page an inspector is null
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use item inspector instead of ActiveInspector :

```
 var document = item.GetInspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;
 if (document != null)
 {
    //code here....
 }
```